# OsiriX will no longer launch. Console message

Tags: launchd

My OsiriX application will suddenly no longer launch. I then upgraded from Mountain Lion to Mavericks and installed the latest version, 5.8. It will still not launch.

The failure is accompanied by a message: "OsiriX is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash."

Of course, this happens after I download the app. again.

Here is the Console message I found that appears to be relevant:

11/4/13 10:37:49.848 PM launchservicesd[55]: Someone attempted to start application App:"OsiriX" asn:0x0-7b07b pid:5959 refs=6 @ 0x7fdd1ac590b0 but it still has _kLSApplicationLockedInStoppedStateKey=true, so it is is staying stopped. : LASApplication.cp #2468 SetApplicationInStoppedState() q=LSSession 100004/0x186a4 queue
11/4/13 10:37:52.873 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[5961]: Error SecAssessmentCreate: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -67054.)
11/4/13 10:38:05.147 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[147]: ([0x0-0x7b07b].com.rossetantoine.osirix[5959]) Exited: Killed: 9

I'm not a programmer. I'd appreciate thoughts about what to do.

Thanks.

Howard

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same issue. I was running 10.8 Mountain Lion. Tried upgrading to 10.9 Mavericks, but still no lock. Turns out it's Gatekeeper that is blocking the app. Here's how to fix it.

Go into System Preferences->Security&Privacy

Under the General tab, change Allow Downloaded Apps From to Anywhere

Launch Osirix

You will get a dialog about it being downloaded from the internet. Select Open.

Once Osirix has opened, quit the app.

Go back into System Preferences->Security&Privacy, and set Allow Downloaded Apps From to whatever it was set at previously (probably Mac App Store and identified developers).

That's it. Once you've gotten Osirix to open once, Gatekeeper won't bother you about it anymore.

Hope that helps. It fixed my issue, and it sounds like you have exactly the same situation.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you **very much.** I would never have guessed.